# Enable adblock on newtab

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I have an iFrame on a newtab, which contains an ad. If possible, how can I block it?

Here is the rule I'm using:

```
https://m.yahoo.com/w/ygo-mail/##DIV#ad-container
```

I'm using Chrome and Adblock on Windows 7 64 bit. The newtab extension is [iChrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ichrome-new-tab/iccjgbbjckehppnpajnmplcccjcgbdep).

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The rule above blocks the entire iFrame, but blocking its parent with `https://m.yahoo.com/w/ygo-mail/##DIV[class="customAd"]` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [support staff](http://support.getadblock.com/discussions/suggestions/656-why-this-app-can-not-block-the-elements-of-new-tab) of Adblock,

> For security reasons, Chrome will not allow extensions to interfere with 
>   the new tab page. They can, however, replace your new tab with something 
>   else, with extensions such as "Tab for a Cause" and "Awesome New Tab Page" 
>   on the Chrome Web Store doing just that.
>
> If you don't like the built-in New Tab page, then you can change it using 
>   extensions like the ones I mentioned above by installing them from the 
>   Chrome Web Store.

This means elements originating from `chrome://newtab` can't be blocked, and I think this also means that Adblock is disabled altogether on new tabs.